# how to use join table with like in codeigniter and also with multi column in like

Tags: codeigniter

how to use join table with like in codeigniter and also with multi column in like.

$search_input=$this->input->get('search_input', true);

```
   if($search_input!=''){


     $this->db->like('block.name','building.name' ,$search_input);


   } 
   $tempdb = clone $this->db;
   $total_row=  $tempdb->from('block')->count_all_results();
   $this->db->limit($perpage, $page); 
   $this->db->order_by("block.id", "desc");
  $this->db->join('building','building.id=block.building_name');

   $result = $this->db->select('block.id,block.name,building.name as building_name')->get('block')->result_array();
   $data=array();
   $data['block_data'] = $result;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: this is complete info sir

Comment: "Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->like('block.name',$search_input);
$this->db->or_like('building.name', $search_input);
$this->db->group_end();
```